# VB .NET 2003 platform: How can I capture CMD output?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Target:
Send commands to a CMD.
Retrieve their corresponding output (result).
Present the output in a TextBox.

Example:
send "ipconfig" to CMD.
Present the output (result) of the command in Text1 TextBox.

Thank you all,
O.P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Tobias, with your help I was managed to build a full solution to my needs.

For those of you who need such solution, I have used a regular Form with a simple button and a Text Box to obtain the output of a CMD command:

```
' Under the Relevant Button click method:
' Note: One should add relevant referrences in order for it to work
' I have added most of them without the need to figure out which one specifically :) 

Dim myProcess As Process = New Process
Dim s As String
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
myProcess.Start()

Dim sIn As System.IO.StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
Dim sOut As System.IO.StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
Dim sErr As System.IO.StreamReader = myProcess.StandardError

sIn.AutoFlush = True
sIn.Write("ipconfig" & System.Environment.NewLine)
sIn.Write("exit" & System.Environment.NewLine)
s = sOut.ReadToEnd()

If Not myProcess.HasExited Then
    myProcess.Kill()
End If
cmdOutputTextBox.Text = s
cmdOutputTextBox.Visible = True
sIn.Close()
sOut.Close()
sErr.Close()
myProcess.Close()
```

Thanks - I hope it helped you.

O.P

Answer (score 1):

you can start an expernal process by using System.Diagnostics.Process:

Start of class:

```
Private WithEvents m_process As System.Diagnostics.Process
```

In your method:

```
        pi = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        pi.Arguments = ...
        pi.FileName = ...
        pi.WorkingDirectory = ...
        pi.UseShellExecute = True
        pi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        pi.RedirectStandardError = True
        pi.CreateNoWindow = True

        m_process = New Process
        m_process.StartInfo = pi
        m_process.Start()
        m_process.BeginOutputReadLine()
        m_process.BeginErrorReadLine()
        m_process.WaitForExit()
```

Listen to the output/error by

```
Private Sub m_process_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles m_process.OutputDataReceived
```

and

```
Private Sub m_process_ErrorDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles m_process.ErrorDataReceived
```

Comment: Hi Tobias,

I am trying to implement it but with no success.
I am trying to combine the method content but get errors.

Can you please advice?
Thanks,
Your help is much appreciated.